# Implementing json marshaller over embedded stuct in Go

Tags: json, go

I have a struct that I would like to efficiently JSON encode:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    *Meta
    Contents []interface{}
}

type Meta struct {
    Id int
}
```

The struct contains meta data of a known form and Contents of an unknown form, The contents list is populated during runtime, so I don't really have control over them. To improve Go's marshalling speed, I would like to implement the Marshaller interface over the Meta struct. The Marshaller interface looks like this:

```
type Marshaler interface {
        MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
}
```

Please keep in mind that the Meta struct is not as simple as shown here. I've tried implementing the Marshaler interface over the Meta struct, but it seems that when I then JSON marshal MyStruct, the result is only the result returned by the Meta marshalling interface.

So my question is: How can I JSON marshal a struct, that contains en embedded struct with its own JSON marshaller and another struct without one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `MarshalJSON` method of the anonymous field `*Meta` will be promoted to `MyStruct`, the `encoding/json` package will use that method when MyStruct will be marshalled.

What you can do is, instead of letting `Meta` implement the `Marshaller` interface, you can implement the interface on MyStruct like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "strconv"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    *Meta
    Contents []interface{}
}

type Meta struct {
    Id int
}

func (m *MyStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    // Here you do the marshalling of Meta
    meta := `"Id":` + strconv.Itoa(m.Meta.Id)

    // Manually calling Marshal for Contents
    cont, err := json.Marshal(m.Contents)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Stitching it all together
    return []byte(`{` + meta + `,"Contents":` + string(cont) + `}`), nil
}


func main() {
    str := &MyStruct{&Meta{Id:42}, []interface{}{"MyForm", 12}}

    o, err := json.Marshal(str)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(o))
}
```

> {"Id":42,"Contents":["MyForm",12]}

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Hh4ogeIu79)