# Is there a way to decode JSON in Go with converting types?

Tags: json, parsing, go

I'm working with an API which can return one value as int if it's zero and as string if it's not zero and I want a decoder which will decode these two JSONs correctly into struct

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "rating": 0
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "rating": "2"
}
type User struct {
  Id int64 `json:"id"`
  Rating int64 `json:"rating,string"`
}
```

So it should try to convert any JSON type (int, float, string) to type specified in struct and raise error only if it isn't possible. Standard json.Decoder doesn't do that.

Or maybe there is some more customizable json parsing library?

Comment: Use a custom type that implements the json.Unmarshaler/Marshaler interface and does what you want it to do.

Comment: the stdlib already provide all the necessary tools to work with json, even this case, it is advised to read the friendly documentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527887/implementing-json-marshaller-over-embedded-stuct-in-go and the first example in https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Comment: @mkopriva, you suggest to implement method `UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error` and parse manually? It's too much of work, there a lot of fields which can randomly change their type(really weird api)

Comment: @mh-cbon, I don't want to parse all the fields manually, there are a lot of them, maybe there is the way to set-up hook for parsing particular type?

Comment: found this one https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/dealing-with-json-with-non-homogeneous-types-in-go.html not the best one though, because it needs you to convert FlexInt to int every time you access it

Comment: @devalone first: your question doesn't specify what the API that you're dealing with *is*. A single custom type that knows how to unmarshal/marshal itself from/to `int`, `float`, `string` is not "too much" work, it's actually a simple solution to a simple problem. Second: if you're looking for library suggestions then your question falls into the off-topic category: (*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*)

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: @mkopriva, it doesn't matter what the API is. I thought about implementing parser for type User, but I already got what you meant, to implement custom type like in link above, good approach, but it needs me to convert this custom type to simple int every time I access it. And I'm not looking for a library, I'm looking for the way to solve this problem, would be better without external libraries.

Comment: @Flimzy, I tried to parse using json.Decoder, like here https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder but it doesn't allow me to parse this flexible type, either int or string.

Comment: @devalone: *Include your code in the question*, along with a complete description of your problem.

Comment: @devalone I brought up the API only because you mentioned it as *"really weird"* in your previous comment which led me to believe that the problem might be more complex than what is described in the original question. If you're dealing with a value whose type is unknown and can be anything then you're stuck with interfaces (don't have to be necessarily empty, but that depends on your use case). Alternatively, if you want to avoid type assertion you could have your custom type be a struct with one field per each possible type, you'll still need to handle the value using conditionals though.

Comment: @mkopriva, as far as I investigated the API(there is no any documentation), the value can be either actual type(int, float) or string. Idea of having struct with field(s) to avoid type assertion sounds interesting, thanks.

Comment: `encoding/json.Number` . Why is it so complicated to read the _whole_ documentation.

Comment: @Volker, the way I eventually implemented it is more convenient in my case, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
type Int64 struct {
        Value int64
}

func (this *Int64) UnmarshalJSON(bytesValue []byte) error {
        stringValue := string(bytesValue)

        if len(stringValue) > 2 {
                if stringValue[0] == '"' && stringValue[len(stringValue)-1] == '"' {
                        stringValue = stringValue[1 : len(stringValue)-1]
                }
        }

        var err error
        this.Value, err = strconv.ParseInt(stringValue, 10, 64)
        return err
}

func (this *Int64) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", this.Value)), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse an `int64` from a JSON string. You can do this using custom types that implement the JSON Unmarshaler interface.

e.g.

```
type User struct {
    Id     int64       `json:"id"`
    Rating Int64String `json:"rating"`
}

type Int64String int64

func (i Int64String) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(strconv.FormatInt(int64(i), 10))
}

func (i *Int64String) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var jstring string
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &jstring)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *(*int64)(i), err = strconv.ParseInt(jstring, 0, 64)
    return err
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d5nnaaHwhsI)

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that I'll need to convert Rating to int64 manually each time I access it

Comment: Yes, but I think it is the cleanest way unless you want to implement unmarshaling for the whole `User` type.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change the api, if thats not possible then you can use the interface type for the rating and manually check for the type during parsing (ints will return as float64):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type User struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`
    Rating interface{} `json:"rating"`
}

func main() {
    usersJson := `[{"id": 1, "rating": 0}, {"id": 2,"rating": "2"}]`

    var users []User

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(usersJson), &users)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err: ",err)
        return
    }

    for _, u := range users {
        switch u.Rating.(type) {
        case float64:
            fmt.Println("its an float64", u.Rating.(float64))
        case string:
            fmt.Println("its an string", u.Rating.(string))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Changing API is not possible